# Test car phone charger amperage

Tags: charger, automotive, testing

I have at car usb charger. It has 2 ports and is rated 2.1A when one port is used and 1A when both ports are used. 
I attached samsung tablet (N8000) witch requires 2A output. So, tablet isn't charging. 
Then i plugged my phone (S5 neo). I drive around with waze turned on (about one hour). My battery does not charged. It even discharge by about 3 or 5 percents. I tried both ports.

Then i found my old 1A charger with single port. That charger charged my phone, with waze turned on. From 80% it goes to 100% within one hour.  In both cases i used the same cable.

So - how i can test charger output amperage? Do i need special equipment or it can be done with multimeter?

Edit:
How I can test if charger really can supply rated amperage? So, how to test its limits ?

Edit2: 
Found this article: http://www.deeptronic.com/variable-dummy-load-for-power-supply-testing/ and I try to build that.

Comment: The problem may also be insufficient voltage out of the "charger".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may also be that the "charger" (actually power supply) is putting out insufficient voltage, instead of insufficient current.

If you don't want to build something like @transistor has described, there are many commercial products out there that will connect between a USB host port or power supply and the cable and display both voltage and current drawn. Search for "USB ammeter" to find them.

Comment: I googled usb ammeter and finally found this: [DROK® Micro Load Tester Board USB DC 0-3A 3-20V ](http://www.amazon.com/DROK-Adjustable-Electronic-Equipment-Resistance/dp/B016EYMVX4/ref=pd_sim_60_2/183-2951330-7166056?ie=UTF8&dpID=418G5FPw8NL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=1ZMZW8FF57ED4NKG7E2D)

Comment: A lower cost alternative if you do not need the load inducing capabilities of the above thing is this one for about one third the price. This one will show you the current draw and voltage on the output of the charger when you plug in a load such as your phone or tablet.  https://www.amazon.com/DROK-Multimeter-Multifunctional-Electrical-Capacity/dp/B00J3JSEG6/ref=pd_bxgy_328_img_3?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00J3JSEG6&pd_rd_r=c4dd3356-1da9-11e9-b113-3f4681716abd&pd_rd_w=KIR8K&pd_rd_wg=l1B3X&pf_rd_p=6725dbd6-9917-451d-beba-16af7874e407&pf_rd_r=FV8D3R00Z7VZWG9MDENG&psc=1&refRID=FV8D3R00Z7VZWG9MDENG

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftk8np.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Monitoring USB current.*

You can use a USB extension lead or cut into one of your existing leads. Add the multimeter set to 'DC A' in series with the red lead.

The D+ lead is actually white. Yellow shown in Figure 1.

Comment: With this I can test how much phone is taking. Right?

Comment: All power to the device connected will be drawn through the red wire, so yes.

Comment: There are also many commercial products available to do the same thing, plus show the voltage at the same time. Search for "usb ammeter" to find them.

Comment: @DoxyLover, that is what I am looking for. Can You write it as answer?